# How to revoke a Fitbit token in swift

Tags: swift, oauth, fitbit

I am trying to revoke a Fitbit token using oAuth in swift. I keep receiving an error below,

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (OAuthSwiftError error -11.)

Here is what I wrote for this:

```
func logout() {
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Atoken")
    let perm = ["token": token]
    let head = ["Authorization": "Basic "+(fitbit_consumer_secret)]
    oauthswift.client.post("https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/revoke", parameters: perm, headers: head, success: { (response) in
        print("Data: \(response)")
    }, failure: { (error) in
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    })
}
```